# Iterator usage in TensorFlow example code

Tags: tensorflow

I am learning TensorFlow (TF), and its been just one day, so I apologize in advance if my doubt is too basic to ask.
I was studying the [linear classification example](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/wide) on the official TF website.

The authors defined a function called `input_fun` to read the data. The function is as follows:

```
def input_fn(data_file, num_epochs, shuffle, batch_size):
  """Generate an input function for the Estimator."""
  assert tf.gfile.Exists(data_file), (
      '%s not found. Please make sure you have either run data_download.py or '
      'set both arguments --train_data and --test_data.' % data_file)

  def parse_csv(value):
    print('Parsing', data_file)
    columns = tf.decode_csv(value, record_defaults=_CSV_COLUMN_DEFAULTS)
    features = dict(zip(_CSV_COLUMNS, columns))
    labels = features.pop('income_bracket')
    return features, tf.equal(labels, '>50K')

  # Extract lines from input files using the Dataset API.
  dataset = tf.data.TextLineDataset(data_file)

  if shuffle:
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=_NUM_EXAMPLES['train'])

  dataset = dataset.map(parse_csv, num_parallel_calls=5)

  # We call repeat after shuffling, rather than before, to prevent separate
  # epochs from blending together.
  dataset = dataset.repeat(num_epochs)
  dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)

  iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
  features, labels = iterator.get_next()
  return features, labels
```

I am not able to understand the second last line. The one-shot-iterator calls `get_next()` only once but shouldn't it iterate on the data multiple times (i.e. number of rows times) to extract the rows, like [this example here](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here, get_next() is basically a dequeue op. The data is in a queue, when you consume (use/call) the element called by get_next(), it is removed from the queue, and the next image/labels is moved in its place, which is dequeued next time you call it.

So currently, this function only returns the tensorflow op for dequeing elements, you can consume it in your training loop.